# How to check the exact type of error in recover?

Tags: go

I'm following this example here:

https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-smarter-error-handling-with-strings-contains-function

```
 if !strings.Contains(err.Error(), "timed out") {
    fmt.Printf("resulting error not a timeout: %s", err)
 }
```

However, if I do that in my code I will get this

> err.Error undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)

I wonder what I'm doing wrong here, and how should I check for an exact error (in my case I want to recover from the error "slice bounds out of range")

Best,

Comment: That tutorial is horrible. Panicking is not a typical way of handling errors, and neither is printing them to stdout and exiting. Identifying errors by their error string is the least preferred way to identify them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use type assertion to get `error` https://play.golang.org/p/BryV7YfZHS

```
defer func(){
    err := recover().(error)
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}()

a := make([]int, 0)
a[1] = 0
```

But I suggest you don't do that. First, you should not use recover. In almost all cases that means you're doing something wrong. Instead, fix the code that panics.

Second, don't use string matching to determine the cause of the error. There're many reasons why it's bad but I will just say that it's not the Go way of doing things. I understand that you may be using API that just doesn't leave you a choice but try to find a better way. Use type assertion, type switch to get the exact error type and go from there.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I was using someone else's code and thus was a bit reluctant to fix the code that does not belong to me. Anyhow, I took your advice and got around it this time without having to do the nasty string matching method. It's good to know that there are options though, I will bookmark your answer. :)